# sql syntax error creating trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to create trigger and I have written this query but this does not execute. Please check my query

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER 'blog_after_insert' AFTER INSERT 
    ON 'blog' 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF NEW.deleted THEN
            SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = 'NEW';
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);
```

I am getting this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''blog_after_insert' AFTER INSERT 
    ON 'blog' 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF NEW.del' at line 2
```

Comment: Just remove the quotes.

Comment: Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please run this query

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER blog_after_insert  AFTER INSERT 
    ON blog 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        IF NEW.deleted THEN
            SET @changetype = "DELETE";
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = "NEW";
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals - object names, like triggers and tables should use forward quotes, or no quotes at all:

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER blog_after_insert AFTER INSERT -- here
    ON blog -- and here
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    -- rest of code...
```

Comment: i have made the changes which you have suggested me, but still getting error.. please look into my query where i am doing mistake ----- CREATE
    TRIGGER blog_after_insert AFTER INSERT -- here
    ON blog -- and here
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 
  IF NEW.deleted THEN
   SET @ changetype = 'DELETE';
  ELSE
   SET @ changetype = 'NEW';
  END IF;
    
  INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @ changetype);

Comment: i have put spaces in special characters @ because stack overflow consider it as a user..